# Can I position my CSS background to "bottom minus x pixels"?

Tags: css, position, background-position

I need to position my background at the bottom of the screen. But on mobile device resolution I want to display it 100px lower than that, like "bottom minus 100px". Is it possible to achieve such a thing in CSS?

Comment: Are you using an background position property for your background or an image tag behind everything? Need to see your code.

Comment: You should add your HTML Markup with other CSS dependencies, it's more guessing than answering without it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, with the four-value syntax of the `background-position` property.

**Presentation**

```
// This two-value declaration
background-position: center bottom
// Is equivalent of this four-value declaration
background-position: center 0px bottom 0px
```

*Disclaimer: the support is Chrome 25+, Firefox 13+, IE9+, Safari 7+*

**In your case**

So you can position your background to "bottom minus 100px":

```
background-position: center bottom -100px
```

**Example:**

```css
.container {
  height: 190px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-align: center;
  
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/140/city/4');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
}
.plus {
  background-position: center bottom 20px;
}
.minus {
  background-position: center bottom -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    background-position:<br>
    center bottom
</div>
<div class="container plus">
    background-position:<br>
    center bottom 20px
</div>
<div class="container minus">
    background-position:<br>
    center bottom -20px
</div>
```

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

Comment: You must be meaning : background-position: center bottom -100px;  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGyLGN

Comment: It depends in which way way you want to move background.

Comment: well he was asking for bottom minus 100px ... ;)

Comment: You're right. So I changed. Thanks. I found it confusing, We generally refer the position from the top of the screen. He could have mean '100vh - 100px"

Comment: Note : You actually can't use `center 0px bottom 0px` : you can't define "100px away from the center" (to where ?). It only works with `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the background property use:

```
.background{
    background-position: center bottom -100px
}
```

If you want to position a tag that resembles a background try using:

```
.background{
    margin-bottom -100px;
}
```

or

```
.background{
    bottom: -100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```